# Show google chart calendar by year DESC

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I am using Google Calendar Chart and I would like to show the 2015 chart first and then 2014, 2013, and so on.

In the example from the google: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar there is no option to do this, even if I put the data in that order.

How can this be accomplished? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could draw three different charts with a DataView for each that isolates each chart to one year, and then layout the 3 charts in reverse order.

Comment: I am trying to avoid that. But, thanks for the reply,

Answer (score -2):

This isn't exactly an ideal solution, but if you were interested you could just manually reverse the year values in the graph if you were willing to reverse them in the data. Like so:

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
  packages: ["calendar"]
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number'});

  dataTable.addRows([
    [new Date(2012, 1, 1), 1],
    [new Date(2013, 1, 1), 2],
    [new Date(2014, 1, 1), 3],
    [new Date(2015, 1, 1), 4]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));
  var options = {};

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', swapYears);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}

// important code, this would be simpler w/ jQuery but here's pure JS
function swapYears() {
  var yearTexts = document.querySelectorAll('[font-size="50"]');

  var years = [];
  yearTexts.forEach(function(text) {
    years.push(text.innerHTML);
  });
  years.reverse();

  for (var i = 0; i < yearTexts.length; i++) {
    yearTexts[i].innerHTML = years[i];
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40cvhekv/)

Output:

[image]

Comment: this swap the year label but all the content stays.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to reverse the years in the data as well.

Comment: As pointed out, this solution is not working at all, only swaps the labels for the years!

Comment: As I clearly said, it's a superficial fix -- you'd have to update your data to match the display. This is the only workaround I'm aware of to solve this problem.